# Certain arithmetic progessions in the Cantor set

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove or disprove  that [the Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) does not include any arithmetic progression of  length 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Because of the linear self similarity maps $C\cap[0,1/3] \rightarrow C$ and $C\cap[2/3,1] \rightarrow C$, given any sequence entirely in either $C\cap[0,1/3]$ or $C\cap[2/3,1]$, you can transform it to a sequence with larger delta still contained in $C$.

Comment: I don't understand it at all. Could you elaborate this?

Comment: How about using the representation of numbers of the Cantor set $C$ in base $3$, to try to form the progression {$c_1,c_2,..c_5$}? The terms $c_i:=0.c_{i1}c_{i2}.....c_{in}....$ have $c_{in}$ in {$0,2$}. Now, start with a term $c_j$ in the Cantor set. What can the $r$ term ( the common difference between consecutive terms ) be ? (note we need $|r| \leq0.2$ to have five terms). If $r:=0.r_1r_2....$ has some $r_j=1 $, can $c_i+r$ be in $C$? Note then $r_j$ cannot have the $1$ in a position where $c_j=0$, or the sum will not be in $C$.

Comment: But if $r_j=1; c_j=2$ , the sum will not be in $C$ either, since the sum will carry.

Comment: I got that: a good idea was unclearly stated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is apparently known that the longest arithmetic progressions in the Cantor set are of length $4$, i.e. there are none of length 5 (or more). See [here](http://math.unt.edu/events/yes-seminar/tba-7) for the abstract of a talk mentioning this result.

*A fill-out based on ashlepper's hint:* Note that there cannot be an AP with at least one term in each of $[0,1/3]$ and $[2/3,1]$, since the removed interval $(1/3,2/3)$ would then force the common  difference of the AP to be at least $1/3$ and there are four gaps in an AP of length 5, giving total length at least $4 \cdot (1/3)=4/3$ which cannot happen as the cantor set is contained in $[0,1]$.

Using the two maps $x \to 3x$ and $x \to 3(1-x)$ (which preserve the cantor set when applied to the intervals $[0,1/3]$ and $[2/3,1]$ respectively), one can successively start with any five term AP and keep mapping it until it is no longer completely contained in either $[0,1/3]$ or in $[2/3,1]$, and then arrive at the above contradiction.

Comment: I couldn't find a link to a proof of the "at most 4 length" for AP in the cantor set, just the above which is only an abstract of a talk. If anyone can find a link it would be great!

Comment: Both Mike Trenfield and Dylan Airy are absent in [zbMATH](http://zbmath.org/authors/?s=0&c=100&q=Dylan+Airey).

Comment: It is an easy fact (if you follow aschepler's hint).  Presumably, that talk also merely mentions that it is an easy fact, then goes on to something more interesting.

Comment: @ GEdgar: Are you serious? Could you give the answer?

Comment: @MarkiyanHirnyk I just added an explanation based on the hint of ashlepper's answer of why no 5 term AP. [Note I didn't find the proof in a paper, but the hint mentioned was enough to give a simple proof, as noted by GEdgar in his comment.